# Ubuntu GNOME Terminal - Can't move cursor to previous line when writing PigLatin/ Hive Commands

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, gnome-terminal

I am trying to write a long Pig Latin command in the grunt shell, which spills over to the second line. But in order to correct an error in line 1, when I try to move the cursor using left arrow key, the cursor gets stuck at the beginning of line 2 and will not move into line 1.

Is there a way I can overcome this issue?

I am working on Cloudera Demo VMWare 0.3.7 with Hadoop, Pig and Hive pre-configured.

Also, please do let me know if I need to post more details.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in hive console

Comment: If you're not dead set on using the shell: either write your commands in a file in a text editor and execute this using Pig or give Hue a shot it has a nice browser based editor.